# Error "Connection Aborted'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

estoy ejecutando un script en Python con Selenium WebDriver

El error es el siguiente:

```
   urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionAbortedError(10053, 'Se ha anulado una conexión establecida por el software en su equipo host', None, 10053, None))
```

Lo estoy probando en mi entorno local donde tengo XAMPP instalado. El script recorre todos los menus y submenus.

Unas veces acaba y otras muestra el error en diferente sitios.

Este es mi código

```
menus=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "id_menu_")]')
print("Menus: "+str(len(menus)))
print("Menus")
print("-----")
for menu in menus:
  #p = menu.find_element_by_tag_name("a")
  print()
  print(menu.text)
  elMenu=driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, menu.text)

  elMenu.click()
  time.sleep(5)
  submenus=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "id_submenu_")]')
  print("SubMenus: "+str(len(submenus)))
  print("SubMenus")
  print("--------")
  for submenu in submenus:
    #p = menu.find_element_by_tag_name("a")
    n_Submenu=submenu.text
    if (n_Submenu!=""):
      print("ID "+n_Submenu+": "+submenu.get_attribute("id"))
      target=submenu.get_attribute("target")
      if (target):
        print("Target "+n_Submenu+": "+submenu.get_attribute("target"))
      ## atrib=menu.get_property('attributes')[0].keys()
      print(n_Submenu)
      time.sleep(3)
  time.sleep(5):
```

¿A que se debe este error?

Saludos

Comment: Haces la coneccion en tu codigo?

Comment: Hola,si claro, me abre la ventana a la url     global driver
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    driver.get("http://local.mipagina/")

Comment: Pero en el código que pones ahi no esta la conexión

Comment: Cierto, pero se realiza

Comment: global driver
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    driver.get("http://mipagina/")

Comment: Debe haber algún problema en el comienzo,durante la conexión

Comment: Creo que puede ser algun problema en tu pc, las causas pueden ser: antivirus o firewall